# Does $A=B$ imply that the rank of $A$ equals the rank of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, transpose

I am trying to understand a poof of the clubs of oddtown theorem, and I am stuck at this step:

If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $AA^T=I_m$, then the rank of $AA^T$ is AT LEAST $m$.

Now if $A=B$ does not this imply that the rank of $A$ equals the rank of $B$? So I thought the rank of $AA^T$ would be exactly $m$, which is the rank of $I_m$.

Comment: The answer to the title question is: yes, of course. If $A=B$, anything about $A$ and $B$ is equal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes that’s the logic thing, but the typo in the proof confused me a little bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be a typo: the proof probably meant that the rank of $A$ is at least $m$ (since the rank of a product of two matrices is at most the minimum of the rank of each factor).